# CloudKit: Couldn't renew our secure session

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cloudkit

I'm trying to request a record from cloudkit with the following code:

```
 CKContainer *myContainer = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [myContainer publicCloudDatabase];

    CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [myContainer privateCloudDatabase];

    [publicDatabase saveRecord:artworkRecord completionHandler:^(CKRecord *artworkRecord, NSError *error){
        if (!error) {

            NSLog(@"saved!!!");

            CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"Artwork"] publicCloudDatabase];
            CKRecordID *artworkRecordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"115"];

            [publicDatabase fetchRecordWithID:artworkRecordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *artworkRecord, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {

                    NSLog(@"error fetching %@", error);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"loading record %@", artworkRecord );
                }
            }];



when I make the request I get this error: "errors === <CKError 0x1780533b0: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't renew our secure session">"
```

But the weird thing is I can save more records with no issues.

I'm using a iPad wifi to test this code

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Strange... The only time when I got this error was when the internet connection was lost. Do you see this error every time or does it sometimes just work? Ah, maybe it's because you are nesting operations. Try putting the fetch within a block like:         NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ ... })

Answer (score 0):

This error is incorrectly returned if CloudKit couldn't reach the server to get its configuration. This most commonly happens if you're trying to access a container that hasn't been provisioned by the server or if there's an issue with your network connection.

This was a bug in CloudKit and more recent iOS and OS X releases should provide a better error message in this case.